# Other Programs Cannot Connect To MySQL

Tags: centos, mysql, timeout

So just recently when installing php-fpm, I had installed a few MySQL packages with it (I believe). I already had mysql installed. However now when any of my programs attempt to access the database, it fails to connect/times out. I can however access the database through ssh (databases, tables, and data are all there).

When I searched for installed MySQL software, these are the results:

```
[root@dev ~]# yum list installed | grep mysql
compat-mysql51.x86_64 5.1.54-1.el6.remi @remi
mysql.x86_64          5.5.39-1.el6.remi @remi
mysql-libs.x86_64     5.5.39-1.el6.remi @remi
mysql-server.x86_64   5.5.39-1.el6.remi @remi
php-mysql.x86_64      5.4.31-1.el6.remi @remi
```

So is this the issue? Or is there another reason none of my programs can connect?

Comment: Firewall rules?

Comment: aha! Thank you, that seems to be it. I also redid my iptables recently, and forgot to reallow it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common problem is firewalling. Another possibility would be that MySQL only listens on unix sockets rather than on IP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11046268/1670183 That helped me open it, worked like a charm

Comment: Awesome - glad it worked :)